# virt-install Centos 6.6 - No option 'boot.iso' in section 'images-x6_64'

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kvm, kickstart

I'm having trouble using kickstart to set up a VM in kickstart for the first time.

I've copied the files off a mounted Centos 6.6 minimal iso to a local ftp server: ftp: //198.162.1.161/pub/inst/

My kickstart configuration file has been copied into ftp: //198.162.1.161/pub/inst/isolinux/ks.cfg (not sure if right spot)

I run:

```
virt-install -n server1.example.com -r 768 --disk /vz/kvm/server1.example.com.img --cdrom ftp://198.162.1.161/pub/inst/ --debug
```

I get:

```
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Launched with command line:
/usr/bin/virt-install -n server1.example.org -r 768 --disk path=/vz/kvm/server1.example.com.img --cdrom ftp://192.168.1.161/pub/inst --debug
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Requesting libvirt URI default
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Received libvirt URI qemu:///system
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Requesting virt method 'default', hv type 'default'.
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Received virt method 'hvm'
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Hypervisor name is 'kvm'
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    DISPLAY is set: graphics defaulting to VNC.
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    --graphics compat generated: vnc
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    DistroInstaller location is a network source.
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Attempting to detect distro:
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Fetching URI: ftp://192.168.1.161/pub/inst/.treeinfo
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Saved file to /var/tmp/virtinst-.treeinfo.hbJW39
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Guest.has_install_phase: True

Starting install...
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    scratchdir=/var/lib/libvirt/boot
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Attempting to detect distro:
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Fetching URI: ftp://192.168.1.161/pub/inst/.treeinfo
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Saved file to /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinst-.treeinfo.1xVxAr
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                            |  592 B     00:00 ... 
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 ERROR    No option 'boot.iso' in section: 'images-x86_64'
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virt-install", line 631, in start_install
    noboot=options.noreboot)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1209, in start_install
    self._prepare_install(meter, dry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 966, in _prepare_install
    meter=meter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/DistroInstaller.py", line 420, in prepare
    dev = self._prepare_cdrom(guest, meter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/DistroInstaller.py", line 258, in _prepare_cdrom
    self.scratchdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/OSDistro.py", line 162, in acquireBootDisk
    scratchdir, type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/OSDistro.py", line 150, in _acquireMedia
    None, media_cb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/OSDistro.py", line 131, in _locationCheckWrapper
    return callback(store, fetcher)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/OSDistro.py", line 145, in media_cb
    media = store.acquireBootDisk(guest, fetcher, progresscb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/OSDistro.py", line 285, in acquireBootDisk
    return fetcher.acquireFile(self._getTreeinfoMedia("boot.iso"),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtinst/OSDistro.py", line 343, in _getTreeinfoMedia
    return self.treeinfo.get("images-%s" % t, mediaName)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ConfigParser.py", line 541, in get
    raise NoOptionError(option, section)
NoOptionError: No option 'boot.iso' in section: 'images-x86_64'
Wed, 03 Jun 2015 17:22:04 DEBUG    Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start server1.example.org
otherwise, please restart your installation.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start server1.example.org
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

/var/lib/libvirt/images -> /vz/kvm as a symlink.

Googling this error says that the issue is a missing .treeinfo, but that exists:

Contents of ftp:// 192.168.1.161/pub/inst/.treeinfo:

```
[general]
family = CentOS
timestamp = 1414159790.06
variant = 
totaldiscs = 1
version = 6.6
discnum = 1
packagedir = 
arch = x86_64

[images-x86_64]

initrd = images/pxeboot/initrd.img

[images-xen]

initrd = images/pxeboot/initrd.img

[stage2]
mainimage = images/install.img
```

Here's a copy-paste of what the pub/inst directory looks like when accessed through the browser:

```
Index of /pub/inst/
Name    Size    Date Modified
[parent directory]      
CentOS_BuildTag 14 B    6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
EFI/        6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
EULA    212 B   6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
GPL 17.6 kB 6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
Packages/       6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
RELEASE-NOTES-en-US.html    1.3 kB  6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6    1.7 kB  6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Debug-6  1.7 kB  6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Security-6   1.7 kB  6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Testing-6    1.7 kB  6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
TRANS.TBL   3.3 kB  6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
images/     6/3/15, 9:21:00 PM
isolinux/       6/3/15, 9:19:00 PM
repodata/       6/3/15, 9:17:00 PM
```

Updated troubleshooting:

- Determined it's not SELinux doing it (suspected permissions issue)
- Tried mkisofs to make a new iso out of the files with the ks.cfg file built in, mounted the iso, copied THOSE files into the FTP directory...still nada

Comment: Does the FULL Tree exist or just the  .treeinfo if it doesn't that could /would cause that error to be thrown..

Comment: Added a copy-paste of the pub/inst directory contents as seen through the browser (.treeinfo not shown because it's a hidden file of course)

Comment: Well unless those are empty dirs, check the status of  virtsh

Comment: They're not empty. Copied straight off a CentOS iso. Do you mean virsh? That's running, too. I thought it might be SELinux, but disabling that doesn't work either.

Comment: ls -Z  on the parent  tree dir  look sane?   should be  system domain